# How can I use recursion to get all possible combinations of these List's of int's?

Tags: c#, algorithm, recursion

I'm using C#.

I have ***n*** number of lists that contain ***x*** number of ints.

How can I write a recursive method to give me all the combinations of these integers?

I want to use a class to move the data around because I'm not sure if you can have lists of lists.  So if i have a class

```
 public class IdContainer
```

that has

```
 public List<int> Id's
```

Each 'combination' should have  **n** number of ints in it.  So if I have 4 Lists as input each combination has 4 ints.

I want to have a method

```
public List<IdContainer> RecurseThroughIds(List<IdContainer> lists)
```

that will return the combinations of Id's

So for example if i had four lists

```
**List 1**
10

**List 2**
15
17

**List 3**
34
38

**List 4**    
44
45
46
```

I would have 12 different combinations (I believe)..

```
10
15
34
44

10
15
34
45

10
15
34
46
```

those would be the first 3 combinations

I cant wrap my head around a base case for this problem.  I know this is fairly straight forward and not a difficult problem but i am struggling with it right now.

Comment: Of course you can have lists of lists.

Comment: Does it **have** to be recursive? Or are you going to be ok with a non-recursive solution?

Comment: I thought recursion would be a cool way to do it.  They marked my question as a duplicate though. and the answer to the other question works, i just wish i could solve it on my own.